# flutter emulator not runing

Tags: flutter, dart, emulation, android-studio-3.0

I am a beginner to flutter, I started learning a few weeks ago and I have been following a tutorial. and I tried running an emulator(Nexus 6) but it keeps on crashing and it just shows a black screen.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjwR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Emulator with a PlayStore sign (While downloading the emulator it would show).

If not please use download the relevant emulator with playstore sign.